# Unable to send unique product id using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

i am trying to send product id using ajax but i am getting same id always

```
{% for product in products %}

    <div id="product">
    <a href = '#'>
    {{ product.id }}


<form id="productfrm"> 
<input type = "hidden" name = "productid" value="{{ product.id }}">
</form>
</a>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

here is the ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#product>a').on('click',function(){ 
            event.preventDefault();   
            var fData = $("#productfrm").serialize();
            console.log(fData)
            $.ajax({        
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'storeView'  user=store.user %}",
                data: fData,
                success: function(data){   
                    alert('success');
                },

                 error: function(response, error) {
                    alert(error);  
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

what can i do to send unique product id on the click of div 
thanks in advance

Comment: You've multiple forms with same id?

Comment: what can i do to solve it bro

Comment: Why are you having a form here at all? You can pass productId as query parameter or path parameter.

Comment: I would rather have a function which accepts a productId, and then set onclick listener on href: `<a href = '#' onclick="getStoreView({{ product.id }})">`'

Comment: ajax request is different from form submission. you either have to submit form without ajax or use only ajax call only. or before sending ajax request, obtain the id from hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't seem to be requiring a form here. If you want to fetch some data based on `productId` clicked, just have an onclick listener on your hyperlink:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <a href = '#' onclick="getStoreView(e, {{ product.id }})">
    {{ product.id }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

And then in your js, have that function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStoreView(event, productId) {
        event.preventDefault();   
        console.log(fData);
        // Send productId as query param of url
        $.ajax({        
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'storeView'  user=store.user %}",
            data: fData,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },

            error: function(response, error) {
                alert(error);  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: getting unexpected token )

Answer (score 0):

Like Rohit commented, you should not use the same ID more than once on a page. Everytime your loop renders a product, it will print a form with the ID "productfrm". You are using this as the selector for fData var and that is where your script goes wrong. jQuery does not know using this selector that you are looking for the form within the current product.

One thing you could do is remove the ID from the form. Then change

```
var fData = $("#productfrm").serialize();
```

to

```
var fData = $(this).find('form').serialize();
```

That should do the job. However, it is not good practice to put a form within an anchor tag.